# When #botframework is going to develop connector for Viber?

Tags: botframework, botconnector

Good day. We're going to develop chatbot based on microsoft bot framework (#botframework). But at the moment there is no connector for Viber (#botconnector). Does someone know if it'll be developed/ And if yes, then when?
Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month ago the BotFramework team said that they don't have immediate plans for a Viber channel.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1917